# Deployement Error During Ant Build

Tags: java, web-services, spring, ant

I am using spring and webservice . So i have defined web.xml as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="service" default="deploy">
    <property name="builddir" value="build" />
    <property name="srcdir" value="../src" />
    <property name="deploydir" value="deploy" />
    <property name="wardir" value="../WebContent"/>
    <property name="libdir" value="${wardir}/WEB-INF/lib/" />


    <target name="cleanstart">
        <delete dir="${builddir}" failonerror="true" />
        <echo message="Creating build directories" />
        <mkdir dir="${builddir}" />
        <mkdir dir="${builddir}/service/WEB-INF/classes" />
        <mkdir dir="${deploydir}" />
    </target>

    <target name="service.war">

        <path id="basepath">
            <!--<fileset dir="${libdir}">
                <include name="**/*.jar" />
            </fileset>
            -->
            <fileset dir="${wardir}/WEB-INF/lib">
                <include name="**/*.jar" />
            </fileset>

        </path>
        <javac srcdir="${srcdir}/" destdir="${builddir}/service/WEB-INF/classes">
            <classpath refid="basepath" />
        </javac>

        <war warfile="${builddir}/service.war" webxml="${wardir}/WEB-INF/web.xml" update="update">
            <classes dir="${builddir}/service/WEB-INF/classes" />
            <fileset dir="${wardir}">
                <exclude name="**/*web.xml" />
            </fileset>

        </war>
    </target>


    <target name="deploy" depends="cleanstart, service.war">
        <copy file="${builddir}/service.war" todir="${deploydir}">
        </copy>
    </target>

</project>
```

And defined beans.xml for spring and Loaded the spring using the below code:

```
ServletConfig servletConfig ;
ServletContext servletContext = servletConfig.getServletContext();
WebApplicationContext context = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
```

During ant build i got exception as below:

```
   service.war:
            [javac] /home/vshankar/service_spring/buildTools/build.xml:36: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
            [javac] Compiling 20 source files to /home/vshankar/service_spring/buildTools/build/service/WEB-INF/classes
            [javac] /home/vshankar/service_spring/src/com/f/a/services/servicename/Service.java:6: package javax.servlet does not exist
            [javac] import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
            [javac]                     ^
            [javac] /home/vshankar/service_spring/src/com/f/a/services/servicename/Service.java:7: package javax.servlet does not exist
            [javac] import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
            [javac]                     ^
            [javac] /home/vshankar/service_spring/src/com/f/a/services/servicename/Service.java:49: cannot find symbol
            [javac] symbol  : class ServletConfig
            [javac] location: class com.f.a.services.servicename.Service
            [javac]     ServletConfig servletConfig ;
            [javac]     ^
            [javac] /home/vshankar/service_spring/src/com/f/a/services/servicename/Service.java:50: cannot find symbol
            [javac] symbol  : class ServletContext
            [javac] location: class 
com.f.a.services.servicename.Service
            [javac]     ServletContext servletContext = servletConfig.getServletContext();
            [javac]     ^
            [javac] 4 errors
```

Can any one help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the servlet jar-file to your classpath while building your project. (please note that it is discouraged to package this file in your ear/war-file)

Comment: Yeah if i include the servlet-api.jar file then during deployment of war file to webapps i got another exception is 26 Jul, 2012 12:55:03 PM com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener contextDestroyed
INFO: WSSERVLET13: JAX-WS context listener destroyed